# How to continue looping in multiple for loops when exception DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX occurred in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have been searching all forums and I did not find any good explanations of how to continue looping where exceptions occur in multiple 'for loops'.

I have the below 'for loop' where on a lot of occasions the unique constraints errors occur. I want to log the exception and continue to loop. I know how to do in one 'for loop', but I cannot figure it how to do it in multiple as the code stops in the 'LOOP 2', and 'CONTINUE' seems to be not working. What am I missing here?

```
--- MAIN LOOP --

DECLARE

BEGIN
     
   FOR v_client_id IN cur_client_id LOOP -- 1 LOOP
     
     FOR dept IN v_dept_type.first..v_dept_type.last LOOP -- 2 LOOP
        
         v_SQL_INSERT:='INSERT INTO clients VALUES( some values )';
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL_INSERT;
            
        FOR v_ip_client_dept IN ASCII('A') .. ASCII('Z') LOOP -- 3 LOOP

            v_SQL_INSERT:='INSERT INTO clients VALUES( some values ';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL_INSERT;

            v_SQL_INSERT:='INSERT INTO clients VALUES( some values ';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL_INSERT;
            
        END LOOP; -- 3 LOOP
            
     END LOOP; -- 2 LOOP
   
   END LOOP; -- 1 LOOP
   
END;`

--- BELOW IS WHAT I TRIED SO FAR

1.

DECLARE

BEGIN
     
   FOR v_client_id IN cur_client_id LOOP -- 1 LOOP
     
     FOR dept IN v_dept_type.first..v_dept_type.last LOOP -- 2 LOOP
        BEGIN
         v_SQL_INSERT:='INSERT INTO clients VALUES( some values )';
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL_INSERT;
         
          EXCEPTION
            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OH DEAR. I THINK IT IS TIME TO PANIC!');
                CONTINUE;
         END;
            
        FOR v_ip_client_dept IN ASCII('A') .. ASCII('Z') LOOP -- 3 LOOP
            
            BEGIN
            v_SQL_INSERT:='INSERT INTO clients VALUES( some values ';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL_INSERT;
            
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OH DEAR. I THINK IT IS TIME TO PANIC!');
                CONTINUE;
            END;
            
            BEGIN
            v_SQL_INSERT:='INSERT INTO clients VALUES( some values ';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL_INSERT;
            
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OH DEAR. I THINK IT IS TIME TO PANIC!');
                CONTINUE;
            END;
            
        END LOOP; -- 3 LOOP
            
     END LOOP; -- 2 LOOP
   
   END LOOP; -- 1 LOOP
   
END;

2. 

DECLARE

BEGIN
     
   FOR v_client_id IN cur_client_id LOOP -- 1 LOOP
     
     FOR dept IN v_dept_type.first..v_dept_type.last LOOP -- 2 LOOP
        BEGIN
         v_SQL_INSERT:='INSERT INTO clients VALUES( some values )';
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL_INSERT;
            
        FOR v_ip_client_dept IN ASCII('A') .. ASCII('Z') LOOP -- 3 LOOP
            
            BEGIN
            v_SQL_INSERT:='INSERT INTO clients VALUES( some values ';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL_INSERT;
            
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OH DEAR. I THINK IT IS TIME TO PANIC!');
                CONTINUE;
            END;
            
            BEGIN
            v_SQL_INSERT:='INSERT INTO clients VALUES( some values ';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL_INSERT;
            
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OH DEAR. I THINK IT IS TIME TO PANIC!');
                CONTINUE;
            END;
            
        END LOOP; -- 3 LOOP
            
     END LOOP; -- 2 LOOP
     EXCEPTION
           WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OH DEAR. I THINK IT IS TIME TO PANIC!');
               CONTINUE;
        END;
   
   END LOOP; -- 1 LOOP
   
END;
```

Comment: Why dynamic SQL? As it currently is, there's nothing *dynamic* here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `CONTINUE` keyword. As the official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/CONTINUE-statement.html) states: *The CONTINUE statement exits the current iteration of a loop*.

The exception is trapped in the `EXCEPTION` block. If an exception is not re-raised, the next block will be executed.

Here is a similar example:

```
declare
  l_nr NUMBER;
begin
  for i in 1 .. 3 loop
    if i = 2 then
      begin
        l_nr := 'x';
      exception when value_error then
        dbms_output.put_line('iteration '||i ||': value error'); 
        CONTINUE;
      end;
    else
      dbms_output.put_line('iteration '||i ||': all ok');
    end if;
    dbms_output.put_line('iteration '||i ||': last log');
  end loop;
end;
/

iteration 1: all ok
iteration 1: last log
iteration 2: value error
iteration 3: all ok
iteration 3: last log
```

Note that iteraction 2 does not have the "last log" line. That is because the `CONTINUE` keyword exits the current iteration and moved to iteration 3. If you comment out the `CONTINUE` keyword it will return

```
iteration 1: all ok
iteration 1: last log
iteration 2: value error
iteration 2: last log
iteration 3: all ok
iteration 3: last log
```

So for your code, try:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
     
   FOR v_client_id IN cur_client_id LOOP -- 1 LOOP
     
     FOR dept IN v_dept_type.first..v_dept_type.last LOOP -- 2 LOOP
        BEGIN
         v_SQL_INSERT:='INSERT INTO clients VALUES( some values )';
         EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL_INSERT;
         
          EXCEPTION
            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OH DEAR. I THINK IT IS TIME TO PANIC!');
                --CONTINUE;
         END;
            
        FOR v_ip_client_dept IN ASCII('A') .. ASCII('Z') LOOP -- 3 LOOP
            
            BEGIN
            v_SQL_INSERT:='INSERT INTO clients VALUES( some values ';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL_INSERT;
            
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OH DEAR. I THINK IT IS TIME TO PANIC!');
                --CONTINUE;
            END;
            
            BEGIN
            v_SQL_INSERT:='INSERT INTO clients VALUES( some values ';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQL_INSERT;
            
            EXCEPTION
            WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OH DEAR. I THINK IT IS TIME TO PANIC!');
                --CONTINUE;
            END;
            
        END LOOP; -- 3 LOOP
            
     END LOOP; -- 2 LOOP
   
   END LOOP; -- 1 LOOP
   
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and example! Helped a lot. It made my code run as expected. P.S. I think I have had tried the same but with 'CONTINUE' and as per you explanation it was not needed and it was skipping to the next 'for', which was wrong.